# how do we check effectively and maintain kdb process health status and latest table count on the process for Windows OS

Tags: kdb

Note: This is for Windows OS.

I have a kdb plant which runs on windows OS. I want to monitor its health in a table like format.
The goal is just by looking at the table, one can tell

1. list of all available host
2. list of all available ports for each host
3. if the process if available or not, if its down/busy or up.
4. if the process if up, then how many tables are present on that process.
5. whats the latest count of data is there in the table.
6. Keep updating the table evey 5-10 mins, maybe we can use a timer here to update.

for now, I have 3 host.
10.10.1.101
10.10.1.215
10.10.1.303

and the port are,
for 10.10.1.101 , we have about say 30 process series from 1000-1030. (10.10.1.101:1000;10.10.1.101:1001;10.10.1.101:1002...10.10.1.101:1030)
and same series for other host.

and in 1 host:port 10.10.1.101:1000, we have say 5-10 tables.

How do we do it without using loops here?

Note: This is for Windows OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some links to resources which could be useful:

- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zw-handles
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zts-timer
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/count/
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/tables/
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/each/
- https://code.kx.com/q/kb/using-dotz/
- https://github.com/simongarland/dotz/blob/master/traceusage.q

Comment: thank you Rianoc, I had started looking into those links.